# How can a touchscreen be made to disable temporarily while an active digitiser is in use?

Tags: thinkpad, multi-touch, touchscreen, wacom

I have a ThinkPad Yoga which features both a capacitive touchscreen and a Wacom digitiser. I can disable the touchscreen manually (using something such as `xinput disable <id>` in a command activated by a Unity launcher icon), but I would prefer a more automated approach. Samsung devices such as the Galaxy Note 3 and 8 (which feature touchscreens and Wacom digitisers together also) disable the touchscreen whenever the active digitiser is active (i.e., near the screen). How could I have similar functionality on the ThinkPad Yoga? Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a script for that, see here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2193327
Now I'm on getting the special keys above F[9-12] to work...if you've found something...

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much for that. The parsing of the xinput test approach is a clever trick. I'm pulling together a little PyQt utility that is to contain many of these tricks. I'll post it to [the thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2193327).

Comment: sorry d3pd, I've edited that script since then. Parsing xinput test wasn't reliable enough on a multicore processor since the script could miss the signal...meaning the touchscreen would stay disabled, Ouch! The new approach works a lot better, recheck it.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for the update. I want to add more to it, but you can find my initial rough attempt at that little PyQt utility I mentioned [here](https://github.com/wdbm/spin/blob/master/spin.py).